# Как сделать запрос для получения всех объявлений с определенными тегами в Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

У меня есть модель объявлений `Ad`, модель тегов `Tag` и реализованная связь 'многие ко многим' между ними.

Я хочу на основе запроса пользователя выдать ему все объявления, где есть выбранные им теги.

Вот мой запрос на основе Eloquent, где я хочу получить объявления, к которым привязан тег с id = 7:

```
 $allAd = Ad::with(['tags' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', 7);
    }])->get();
```

Делая такой запрос я получаю абсолютно все объявления, как если бы запросил `Ad::all();`, включая те, где ни одного тега нет.

Что я делаю не так и как правильно составить запрос, который бы выдал только объявления с выбранными тегами?

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Выложите описание всех трёх связей из ваших моделей. И вы пробовали написать полностью условие - `$query->where('id', '=', 7);` ?

Comment: и почему бы не искать от обратного? От тегов?

Comment: Ну, я размышляю так, мне надо вывести пользователю объявления и я ищу объявления. А от знака равно ничего не поменяется. В моделях все стандартно `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Ad'); ` и `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag');` А что значит "трех связей" ? Связей две. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691421/laravel-eloquent-many-to-many-query-wherein) на англоязычном stackoverflow. Необходимо применять методы `whereHas` и `whereIn`, а `$tagsId` должен быть массивом значений.

```
$allAds  = Ad::whereHas('tags', function($query) use($tagsId) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $tagsId);
})->get();
```